# Dell XPS -- no bootable device

Tags: boot, dell, xps

I had a running copy of ubuntu on my laptop but I had to boot from cd-rom to fix file /etc/sudoers that I had inadvertently ruined. Having to boot from legacy cd-rom, I change bios configuration and now I seem unable to boot from ssd disk anymore. Any pointer, hint, suggestion...

Comment: It reads like you need to go back into BIOS and undo the change you did that allowed the booting via cd-rom.  If this is not your issue, it's very unclear as you've provided no details as to any error messages you get or what your issue is.

Comment: Have you tried the Super Grub CD?